# Get single random example from PyTorch DataLoader

Tags: python, pytorch

How do I get a single random example from a PyTorch [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html?highlight=dataloader#torch.utils.data.DataLoader)?

If my `DataLoader` gives minbatches of multiple images and labels, how do I get a single random image and label?

Note that I don't want a single image and label per minibatch, I want a total of one example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to choose specific images from your Trainloader/Testloader, you should check out the [`Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) function from master:

Here's an example how to use it:

```
testset = ImageFolderWithPaths(root="path/to/your/Image_Data/Test/", transform=transform)
subset_indices = [0] # select your indices here as a list
subset = torch.utils.data.Subset(testset, subset_indices)
testloader_subset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(subset, batch_size=1, num_workers=0, shuffle=False)
```

This way you can use exactly one image and label. However, you can of course use more than just one index in your subset_indices.

If you want to use a specific image from your DataFolder, you can use dataset.sample and build a dictionary to get the index of the image you want to use.

Comment: This gives you the first element in the dataset, **not** a random one.

Answer (score 37):

If your `DataLoader` is something like this:

```py
test_loader = DataLoader(image_datasets['val'], batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

it is giving you a batch of size `batch_size`, and you can pick out a single random example by directly indexing the batch:

```
for test_images, test_labels in test_loader:  
    sample_image = test_images[0]    # Reshape them according to your needs.
    sample_label = test_labels[0]
```

---

#### Alternative solutions

1. You can use [RandomSampler](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.RandomSampler) to obtain random samples.
2. Use a `batch_size` of 1 in your DataLoader.
3. Directly take samples from your DataSet like so:

   ```
    mnist_test = datasets.MNIST('../MNIST/', train=False, transform=transform)
   ```

   Now use this dataset to take samples:

   ```
    for image, label in mnist_test:
         # do something with image and other attributes
   ```
4. **(Probably the best)** See [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html#visualize-a-few-images):

   ```
    inputs, classes = next(iter(dataloader))
   ```

Comment: Cheers! For Alternative 1, there needs to be a loop... Is it possible to do something like: `testloader.next()[0]`?

Comment: Take a look at (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/dataloader.html#DataLoader). I think `DataLoader.__iter__` should work or something from `_DataLoaderIter` must. Also, if this answers your question, consider accepting the answer

Comment: You've not really answered my question: 1) will give one image per minibatch, not just one image. 2) violates the plural in the question (I'll edit to make this move obvious) 3) This looks like it will process every example, not just give a single one.

Comment: Well, first thing is that you can use DataLoader multiples times in different loops. Now, my main example would take one image out of a minibatch and then you can break the loop or you can use `__iter__` function of DataLoader to get `next` out of it without a loop. For Alternative 1, a `RandomSampler` returns an `iter` object and you can use `next` to pick out a single image, label (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/sampler.html#RandomSampler). For Alternative 2, yes that violates your specific condition. For Alternative 3, break out of the loop the first time.

Comment: It seems smelly/ugly to make a loop just to break out of it after one iteration. Any ideas?

Comment: I also mentioned the `next` option.

Comment: You did, but on a RandomSampler, which is not answering the question. It seems I mentioned it first however the syntax is gnarly and I've not yet worked out the implementation (I'm in transit).

Comment: Could you define your `DataLoader` please? I will try to find something.

Answer (score 11):

(This answer is to supplement **Alternative 3** of @parthagar's answer)

Iterating through `dataset` does **not** return "random" examples, you should instead use:

```py
# Recovers the original `dataset` from the `dataloader`
dataset = dataloader.dataset

# Get a random sample
random_index = int(numpy.random.random()*len(dataset))
single_example = dataset[random_index]
```

Comment: Useful answer. If you want to feed this single_example to a network, you may also need to expand the dimension by 1 to add the batch dimension that the dataloader returns by iteration. From my code:
        item=dataset[frame_number] # get a particular frame
        voxel = torch.unsqueeze(item['events'], dim=0).to(device)# we need to add a singleton dimension at front to make it look like batch 1 sample

Answer (score 8):

### TL;DR:

The general form to get a single example from a `DataLoader` is:

```
list = [ x[0] for x in iter(trainloader).next() ]
```

In particular to the question asked, where minbatches of images and labels are returned:

```
image, label = [ x[0] for x in iter(trainloader).next() ]
```

---

#### Possibly interesting information:

To get a single minibatch from the `DataLoader`, use:

```
iter(trainloader).next()
```

When running something like `for images, labels in dataloader:` what happens under the hood is an iterator is created via `iter(dataloader)`, then the iterator's `.next()` is called on each loop execution.

---

To get a single image from a `DataLoader`, which returns images and labels use:

```
image = iter(trainloader).next()[0][0]
```

This is the same as doing:

```
images, labels = iter(trainloader).next()
image = images[0]
```

Comment: **Note:** for this to produce a random sample you must ensure `shuffle=True` in the DataLoader construction.

Answer (score 7):

#### Random sample from `DataLoader`

Assuming `DataLoader(shuffle=True)` was used in its construction, a single random example can be drawn from the DataLoader with:

```py
example = next(iter(dataloader))[0]
```

#### Random sample from `Dataset`

If that is not the case, you can draw a single random example from the Dataset with:

```py
idx = torch.randint(len(dataset), (1,))
example = dataset[idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to get random sample is to set `shuffle=True` for the `DataLoader`, and the key for getting the single image is to set the batch size to 1.

Here is the example after [loading the mnist dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56672709/5884955).

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset, TensorDataset
bs = 1
train_ds = TensorDataset(x_train, y_train)
train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size=bs, shuffle=True)

for xb, yb in train_dl:
    print(xb.shape)
    x = xb.view(28,28) 
    print(x.shape)
    print(yb)
    break #just once

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(x, cmap="gray")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## You can simply just covert trainloader to iterable, then get next batch by writing this code

```
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = next(dataiter)
```

**Here is an example**

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

batch_size = 4

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                       download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
           'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')


# functions to show an image


def imshow(img):
    img = img / 2 + 0.5     # unnormalize
    npimg = img.numpy()
    plt.imshow(np.transpose(npimg, (1, 2, 0)))
    plt.show()


# get some random training images
dataiter = iter(trainloader)
images, labels = next(dataiter)

# show images
imshow(torchvision.utils.make_grid(images))
# print labels
print(' '.join(f'{classes[labels[j]]:5s}' for j in range(batch_size)))
```

Refernces: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html