# How to get a specific sample from pytorch DataLoader?

Tags: pytorch

In Pytorch, is there any way of loading a *specific* single sample using the `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` class? I'd like to do some testing with it.

The [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-cifar10-tutorial-py) uses

```
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(...)
images, labels = next(iter(trainloader))
```

to fetch a *random* batch of samples. Is there are way, using `DataLoader`, to get a *specific* sample?

Cheers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61389393/6075699

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Turn off the `shuffle` in `DataLoader`
- Use `batch_size` to calculate the batch in which the desired sample you are looking for falls in
- Iterate to the desired batch

#### Code

```
import torch 
import numpy as np
import itertools

X= np.arange(100)
batch_size = 2

dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(X, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
sample_at = 5
k = int(np.floor(sample_at/batch_size))

my_sample = next(itertools.islice(dataloader, k, None))
print (my_sample)
```

Output:

```
tensor([4, 5])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mujjiga, works like a charm!

Comment: Great answer, exactly what was required.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to get a specific signle sample from your dataset you can
you should check Subset class.(https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset)
something like this:

```
indices =  [0,1,2]  # select your indices here as a list  
subset = torch.utils.data.Subset(train_set, indices)
trainloader = DataLoader(subset , batch_size =  16  , shuffle =False) #set shuffle to False 

for image , label in trainloader:
   print(image.size() , '\t' , label.size())
   print(image[0], '\t' , label[0]) # index the specific sample
```

here is a useful link if you want to learn more about the Pytorch data loading utility
(https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html)