# How to split data into train and test sets using torchvision.datasets.Imagefolder?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, pytorch

In my custom dataset, one kind of image is in one folder which torchvision.datasets.Imagefolder can handle, but how to split the dataset into train and test?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a custom dataset into training and test datasets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544730/how-do-i-split-a-custom-dataset-into-training-and-test-datasets)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`torch.utils.data.Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) to split your `ImageFolder` dataset into train and test based on indices of the examples.
For example:

```py
orig_set = torchvision.datasets.Imagefolder(...)  # your dataset
n = len(orig_set)  # total number of examples
n_test = int(0.1 * n)  # take ~10% for test
test_set = torch.utils.data.Subset(orig_set, range(n_test))  # take first 10%
train_set = torch.utils.data.Subset(orig_set, range(n_test, n))  # take the rest
```

Comment: In this way, the rate between the label can be maintained?

Comment: @toy_programmer you might need to be more careful I. the way you select indices for train/test

Comment: Agree with @Shai. If the data is ordered you will take only the first 10% of the classes

Comment: better use [`random_split`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html?highlight=random_split#torch.utils.data.random_split)