# Validation dataset in PyTorch using DataLoaders

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I want to load the MNIST dataset in PyTorch and Torchvision, dividing it into train, validation, and test parts. So far I have:

```py
def load_dataset():
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
            '/data/', train=True, download=True,
            transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()])),
        batch_size=batch_size_train, shuffle=True)

    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
            '/data/', train=False, download=True,
            transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()])),
        batch_size=batch_size_test, shuffle=True)
```

How can I divide the training dataset into training and validation if it's in the `DataLoader`? I want to use the last 10000 examples from the training dataset as a validation dataset (I know that I should do a CV for more accurate results, I just want a quick validation here).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a custom dataset into training and test datasets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544730/how-do-i-split-a-custom-dataset-into-training-and-test-datasets)

Comment: @kHarshit yes and no, after further reading it seems it's a more complicated matter. I've found the solution, but it's more complicated than it should be in a normal library.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Splitting the training dataset into training and validation in PyTorch turns out to be much harder than it should be.

First, split the training set into training and validation **subsets** (class `Subset`), which are **not** datasets (class `Dataset`):

```
train_subset, val_subset = torch.utils.data.random_split(
        train, [50000, 10000], generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(1))
```

Then get actual data from those datasets:

```
X_train = train_subset.dataset.data[train_subset.indices]
y_train = train_subset.dataset.targets[train_subset.indices]

X_val = val_subset.dataset.data[val_subset.indices]
y_val = val_subset.dataset.targets[val_subset.indices]
```

Note that this way we **don't** have `Dataset` objects, so we can't use `DataLoader` objects for batch training. If you want to use DataLoaders, they work directly with Subsets:

```
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_subset, shuffle=True, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
val_loader = DataLoader(dataset=val_subset, shuffle=False, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Comment: `val_loader` should take `val_subset` as the dataset argument and not `train_subset`, correct?

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to ensure your splits have balanced classes, you can use `train_test_split` from `sklearn`.

```py
import torchvision
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Subset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

VAL_SIZE = 0.1
BATCH_SIZE = 64

mnist_train = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    '/data/',
    train=True,
    download=True,
    transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()])
)
mnist_test = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(
    '/data/',
    train=False,
    download=True,
    transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([torchvision.transforms.ToTensor()])
)

# generate indices: instead of the actual data we pass in integers instead
train_indices, val_indices, _, _ = train_test_split(
    range(len(mnist_train)),
    mnist_train.targets,
    stratify=mnist_train.targets,
    test_size=VAL_SIZE,
)

# generate a subset based on indices
train_split = Subset(mnist_train, train_indices)
val_split = Subset(mnist_train, val_indices)

# create batches
train_batches = DataLoader(train_split, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
val_batches = DataLoader(val_split, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
test_batches = DataLoader(mnist_test, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True)
```