# Spliting the dataset using SubsetRandomSampler not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I used [`SubsetRandomSampler`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544730/how-do-i-split-a-custom-dataset-into-training-and-test-datasets) to split the training data to train (80%) and validation data (20%). But it is showing the same number of images for both after the split (4996):

```py
>>> print('len(train_data): ', len(train_loader.dataset))
>>> print('len(valid_data): ', len(validation_loader.dataset))
```

```py
len(train_data):  4996
len(valid_data):  4996
```

---

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler

train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                       transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                                            [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder( '/data/images/train', transform=train_transforms )

validation_split = .2
shuffle_dataset = True
random_seed= 42
batch_size = 20

dataset_size = len(dataset) #4996
indices = list(range(dataset_size))
split = int(np.floor(validation_split * dataset_size))

if shuffle_dataset :
    np.random.seed(random_seed)
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
train_indices, val_indices = indices[split:], indices[:split]

train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_indices)
valid_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(val_indices)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=train_sampler)
validation_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=valid_sampler)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`train_loader.dataset` and `validation_loader.dataset` are methods which return the underlying **original dataset** that the loaders sample from (i.e. the original dataset of size 4996).

If you iterate through the loaders themselves you will see they only return as many samples (acounting for batching) as you have included in the index for each sampler, however.